# CSS3 Animation Prevent Inheritance

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have an CSS3 animation which enlarges a div box.
This div contains an child element "p"-tag. When I set the animation class on the div box, the p tag inherits the animation. But I want to run the animation only on the parent div element and not on the child.

How can I prevent animation (-webkit-animation) inheritance?
I tried to set -webkit-animation:none on the child but it doesnt work.

Comment: It works for me without inheritance - http://jsfiddle.net/HWpAr/2/

Comment: strange. look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddly/FwHZn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddly/FwHZn/1/

I had to set the width of the "p"-tag. Otherwise the animation will be applied on the div and on the p tag.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using a JQuery animation (height, width in your case) on the div instead so that you can select the particular elements that you wish to animate

Answer (score 0):

There is no animation of the child `p` because the child `p` is rendered inside the `div`. There is only an animation on the rendered `div`. You can try to hide the child `p` with css:

```
div#yourDivId p {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```